Minimum number of vertices for a graph to satisfy properties to make the graph disconnected.
Let G be a graph such that the smallest number of edges needed to be removed from G to produce a disconnected graph is 10, but the smallest number of vertices needed to be removed from G to produce a disconnected graph is 1. Prove that G has at least 21 vertices.
I tried doing a proof by contradiction and tried applying the formula: $\sum \text{deg}(v) = 2|E|$, but did not really make any headway. I tried proving the statement "Assume there exists a graph G such that is has less than 21 vertices such that the smallest number of edges needed to be removed from G to produce a disconnected graph is 10, but the smallest number of vertices needed to be removed from G to produce a disconnected graph is 1.
Any advice on how to prove the statement?

To get some intuition about the problem, try to build a counterexample.

Welcome to MathSE! It will be most helpful if you provide a bit more context to what you've tried, and where you got stuck. You say that you've tried a proof by contradiction. What did that proof look like? Where in the proof did you get stuck? How did you try to apply Euler's Formula? This is all helpful information that can help provide better answers to your question. You also tagged this question as a "planar-graph" question. Is that an assumption you're making about $G$? If so, that should be part of the setup to the problem (we need to know all the information we're working with)!

@Karl In trying to build a counterexample I think the graph in the problem must have one vertex in the middle that connects to at least 10 other vertices on either side that also connect to each other so that it can be removed to make it disconnected? Am I on the right track? Still, I have no idea how to formally prove the statement.

@Kyle edited the problem, thank you for your advice. In my attempt at the proof I really did not get far so I didn't have much to say. Also I erroneously tagged the problem so I fixed it.

Perhaps try to prove it in the following form: if G is a graph that has a cut vertex (removing it disconnects the graph) and has at most 20 vertices (including the cut vertex), then it has an edge cut of at most 9 edges. As you suspect, the edge cut can be formed from edges incident to that cut vertex.
